# matplotlib 3d scatter from 2d numpy array vertices error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, mplot3d

I'm stumped as to why this is not working.  I am pulling a bunch of floating point data in to a numpy array from a csv file, and I just want to create a 3d scatter plot based from 3 of the columns in the array.

```
#import data from the csv file
data = np.genfromtxt('data.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=float, skiprows=1)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(data[:,1], data[:,2], data[:,7], c='r', marker='0')
plt.show()
```

every time i get an assertion error:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/path.pyc in __init__(self, vertices, codes, _interpolation_steps, closed)
127             codes[-1] = self.CLOSEPOLY
128 
--> 129         assert vertices.ndim == 2
130         assert vertices.shape[1] == 2
131 

AssertionError:
```

I have... just figured it out, but i'll post this any way because that is the single most useless error message i have ever encountered.  the problem was here:

```
ax.scatter(data[:,1], data[:,2], data[:,7], c='r', marker='0')
```

marker='0' is invalid, i meant to hit marker='o', once fixed it works just fine.

Comment: Are you really showing the full error message here? Bad error messages are never a good thing. Which matplotlib version is that? If relevant, please report this to the matplotlib project via github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `scatter3D()` method of the `Axes3DSubplot` object:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter3D(data[:,1], data[:,2], data[:,7], c='r', marker='0')
```